# Difference between /dev and /sys

Tags: linux, mount, devices, udev, sysfs

Exactly what is the difference between **devfs** and **sysfs**? Both seem to *maintain a list of hardwares attached to the system*. Then why the need for 2 separate fs even arose? As far as I can get **/sys** maintains somewhat "raw" list of devices(like "ser0"). `udev` acts on those devices, gets various informations and applies various rules to present them as recognizable names which are then mapped onto **/dev**(like "camera"). Is this the only reason? And then we mount the corresponding devices from the **/dev** fs (can't we do that from the **/sys** fs) into the **/media** fs.

I have read the answer at [Difference between /dev and /sys/class?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119680/difference-between-dev-and-sys-class). But I cannot get the sys fs part where it states that

> Sysfs contain the hierarchy of devices, as they are attached to the computer

Are the files in `/sys` not device node files? Then what type of files are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between procfs and sysfs?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/what-is-the-difference-between-procfs-and-sysfs)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The answers to both questions look at `sysfs` from different perspectives and none of the answers to the other question explain how the `/dev` directory relates to `sysfs`.

Answer (score 42):

The `/sys` filesystem (sysfs) contains files that provide information about devices: whether it's powered on, the vendor name and model, what bus the device is plugged into, etc. It's of interest to applications that manage devices.

The `/dev` filesystem contains files that allow programs to access the devices themselves: write data to a serial port, read a hard disk, etc. It's of interest to applications that access devices.

A metaphor is that `/sys` provides access to the packaging, while `/dev` provides access to the content of the box.

The files in `/sys` are not device nodes, but symbolic links and regular files. Those regular files are special in that reading or writing to them invokes file-specific functions in the kernel, like device nodes. The difference is that files in `/sys` work this way because of the filesystem they are on, whereas device nodes work this way due to their device node characteristics (the file type indicating a (block or character) device, and the device major and minor number indicating which device it is).

The reason for `/dev` existing independently of `/sys` is partly historical: `/dev` dates back to the dawn of Unix, while `/sys` is a much more recent invention. If Linux was designed today with no historical background, `/dev/sda` might be `/sys/block/sda/content`.

Comment: See also: `man hier`.

Answer (score 1):

- `/dev` directory allows access to the device via the device files (or device nodes)
- `/sys` directory allows the viewing of the device information and details.

for instance: `cat /sys/block/*/device/serial` (with `*` replaced by `nvme0n1` or `sda` or `hda` ... depending on your case) will print the serial number of the disk storage.